# Trying to retrieve data from a string in database

Tags: php, database, string, foreach, get

I have the following output in one field in Joomla ($item->attribs):

```
{"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"ja_teline_v:p4p50","content_type":"p4p","ads":"1","ctm_boxer":{"name":["Floyd Mayweather","Manny Pacquiao","Wladimir Klitschko","Miguel Cotto","Gennady Golovkin","Sergey Kovalev","Guillermo Rigondeaux","Juan Manuel Marquez","Carl Froch","Saul Alvarez","Danny Garcia","Roman Gonzalez","Amir Khan","Mikey Garcia","Jhonny Gonzalez","Leo Santa Cruz","Adonis Stevenson","Abner Mares","Terence Crawford","Adrien Broner","Timothy Bradley","Juan Francisco Estrada","Robert Guerrero","Bernard Hopkins","Marco Huck","Nicholas Walters","Sergio Martinez","Julio Cesar Chavez Jr","Arthur Abraham","Nonito Donaire","Orlando Salido","Fernando Montiel","Humberto Soto","Marcos Maidana","Naoya Inoue","Donnie Nietes","Alexander Povetkin","Juan Carlos Reveco","Peter Quillin","Lucas Matthysse","Brian Viloria","Jamie McDonnell","Juergen Braehmer","Kell Brook","Deontay Wilder","Erislandy Lara","Jean Pascal","Carl Frampton","Omar Narvaez","Tomoki Kameda"],"rating":["5","5","4","4","3","3","3","4","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","2","3","2","2","3","3","2","3","5","2","2","3","2","3","4","2","3","2","3","3","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","1","1","1","2","1","2","1"],"movement":["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],"record":["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1-0, 1 KO","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1-0","0","0","0","0","0"],"ranking":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50"],"highlight":["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]},"ctm_topic_id":""}
```

How do I retrieve every value from ctm_boxer -> name in a list?

I've tried the below, but to no avail!

```
<?php $boxers = $item->attribs->get('ctm_boxer', array()); ?>
<?php foreach($boxers['name'] as  $index => $boxer_type): ?>
<?php echo $boxer_type; ?>
```

but it's returning 'Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object'

Can anyone help as to why please?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: `$item->attribs` is supposed to return an object of some sort. Are you sure you've set the `$item` variable with an object in the first place?

Comment: It outputs the associated field within the correct table, so I assume so, yes... $item is set as the specific Joomla article in question... Thanks

Comment: What does `var_dump($item->attribs);` output?

Comment: Hi, that's too long to add in a comment in its entirety, but it starts as

Comment: string(2494) "{"show_title":"","link_titles":"","show_tags":"","show_intro":"","info_block_position":"","show_category":"","link_category":"","show_parent_category":"","link_parent_category":"","show_author":"","link_author":"","show_create_date":"","show_modify_date":"","show_publish_date":"","show_item_navigation":"","show_icons":"","show_print_icon":"","show_email_icon":"","show_vote":"","show_hits":"","show_noauth":"","urls_position":"","alternative_readmore":"","article_layout":"ja_teline_v:p4p50","content_type":"p4p","ads":"1","ctm_boxer":{"name":["Floyd Mayweather","Manny Pacquiao","Wla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from `var_dump` inside `$item->attrib` is a `string` shown as `string(2494)`. Not an object/PHP class. That's why you're getting `Fatal Error: Call to a member function on a non-object`. Because again, `$item->attrib` is a normal `string`.

The `->` dereference operator can only be used on PHP Objects/Classes.

[More on how to use the object operator.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

That variable seems to contain a string in JSON format.

Try the following:

```
$BoxerCollectionObject = json_decode($item->attribs);

$boxerArray = $BoxerCollectionObject->ctm_boxer->name;

foreach ($boxerArray as $boxer) {
    var_dump($boxer); //Should output the name of your boxers.
}
```

## [DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iL2hA9)

Answer (score 0):

That's great - thanks - works perfectly... I expanded it a bit with the following to bring in some of the other parts of the string:

```
<?php
$BoxerCollectionObject = json_decode($item->attribs);
$boxerArray = $BoxerCollectionObject->ctm_boxer->name;
$boxerRating = $BoxerCollectionObject->ctm_boxer->rating;
?>
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <?php $i = 1;?>
      <?php $ic = 1;?>
      <?php foreach ($boxerArray as $index => $boxer) : ?>
      <tr itemprop="boxer" class="boxer<?php echo $ic++; ?>">
        <td><strong><?php echo $i++; ?></strong></td>
        <td><span><a href="/index.php?searchword=<?php echo $boxer; ?>&searchphrase=all&Itemid=215&option=com_search"><?php echo $boxer; ?></a></span></td>
        <td itemprop="rating"><?php if ($boxerRating[$index] <= 0): ?>
          <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <?php endif;?>
          <?php if ($boxerRating[$index] == 1): ?>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <?php endif;?>
          <?php if ($boxerRating[$index] == 2): ?>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <?php endif;?>
          <?php if ($boxerRating[$index] == 3): ?>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <?php endif;?>
          <?php if ($boxerRating[$index] == 4): ?>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
          <?php endif;?>
          <?php if ($boxerRating[$index] >= 5): ?>
          <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
          <?php endif;?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Thanks again, Matt.